# Laravel Webklex / laravel-imap GetMessages is so slow

Tags: php, laravel, package, imap, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel  Webklex / laravel-imap package and it working fine
but the $folder->getMessages();
takes too long to respond sometimes i get max_execution time exceeded and the app crashed
any ideas on what could be causing the problem.
here is the code Im using

```
 $client = Client::account('default');
    //Connect to the IMAP Server
    $client->connect();
    
    //Get all folders
    $folders = $client->getFolders();
     
    foreach($folders as $folder){
            if($folder->name==$f){
                $messages = $folder->messages()->all()->get();
                return view('mail',compact('folders','messages','f'));
                
            }
        }
```

Also I tested it with gmail and outlook and its slow for both of them